# Change radio on click with given background color

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to change the Bootstrap v5 class of the buttons when they are clicked. They all have a same background-color constant (#cd6133). However when clicked i'd like then to have the following colors; and also radio button to be hidden and bootstrap button to be visible with provided colors

**btn-default (#cd6133)**

**Entry (#05c46b)**

**Proffessional (#2c2c54)**

**Excutive (#227093)**

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="change" id="entry" value="1" autocomplete="off">Entry
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="change" id="proffessional" value="2" autocomplete="off">Proffessional
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="change" id="excutive" value="3" autocomplete="off">Excutive
        </label>
</div>
```

```
<script>

      $("#cd6133").on("click", function() {
        var classArr = ["#05c46b", "#2c2c54", "#227093"];
        $("#cd6133").removeClass(classArr.toString().replace(/,/g," "));
        var value = $(this).find("input[name='change']").val();
        $(this).addClass(classArr[value - 1]);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Instead of doing `classArr.toString().replace(/,/g," ")` you can simply use `classArr.join(' ')`

Comment: Put the background colours in CSS classes for the individual elements in their selected state. Then you don't need to use JS at all. For example `#entry:checked { backround-color: #05c46b; }`

Comment: @RoboRobok or just pass the array in the first place:  `$("#cd6133").removeClass(classArr)` - see https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/#removeClass-classNames